# How can I correctly document an extension method in C#?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

I am just starting to look at the C# documentation standards. Here's a method that I have:

```
/// <summary>
/// Reformats a key in x.x format to 0x0x format
/// </summary>
/// <param name="dotFormatRowKey">key in ##.## format</param>
public static string DotFormatToRowKey(this string dotFormatRowKey) 
{

    if (! Regex.IsMatch(dotFormatRowKey, @"\d+\.\d+"))
       throw new ArgumentException("Expected ##.##, was " + dotFormatRowKey);

    var splits = dotFormatRowKey.Split('.')
                 .Select(x => String.Format("{0:d2}", Int32.Parse(x)))
                 .ToList();
    var joined = String.Join(String.Empty, splits.ToArray())

    return joined;
}
```

Can someone give me advice on how I should document the input and return parameters for this method. Also when I do this will the documented comments be available to a person if they use VS2010 intellisense?

Comment: What do you mean "how I should document"? Are you asking what you should type or what tags you should use, such as the [returns](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4dcfdeds.aspx) tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for how you should document the parameters: i think thats pretty subjective but the way you did it now looks ok to me. Altho you could maybe change your return variable `joined` into something more verbose, like `"keyFormattedString"` or something.

as for the second part of your question:

> Also when I do this will the documented comments be available to a
>   person if they use VS2010 intellisense?

Quote taken from msdn:

> Extension methods are only in scope when you explicitly import the
>   namespace into your source code with a using directive.

If the method is inside some class in a class library, then they will have to reference that library into their current solution, in order to use/see the method and documented comments. You can basically make a new class library with all your extension methods in it, and then import that DLL to whatever solution you're working on.

Let's say that you have a class library, then you simply add

```
using ExtensionMethodsLib; // or whatever you'll call it
```

to your using statements, on whatever page you might need it.

[Extension methods (msdn)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx)